# I can't run driver.touchAction() because it says "Method not implemented" (yesterday it worked)

Tags: typescript, appium

I had restarted my Mac and suddenly my automation tests (Appium WebdriverIO with Typescript for Android native app testing) stopped working. I deleted NVM and reinstalled a fresh node from brew. After that the tests ran again but with a fault in the method `driver.touchAction()` which throws an error

> Method not implemented

I have tried reinstalling Java, Node in multiple versions, I have changed my Mac envs ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME but anything solves the unknown method problem.

In the internet there isn't much documentation or information

The app is full native and the tests without changing the code worked perfectly the day before I restarted my Mac.

Any further information needed please let me know.

I tried to run my automated tests, I expected the `driver.touchAction()` to work, and I get a "Not implemented method" exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the implementation of the touchAction there was a syntax error I changed it for this and it worked perfectly:

```
await browser.touchAction([
        { action: 'press', x: 200, y: 200 },
        { action: 'moveTo', x: 200, y: 300 },
        'release'
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. The problem is not `touchAction` but `press`. In the newest Appium versions this is not implemented anymore. A bad workaround would be to use `longpress` instead.